# Is cuda atomicAdd operation faster than launch another kernel when we do reduce sum?

Tags: cuda, atomic

I need to sum up a vector, which is longer than the number of threads in a cuda block. So I use multi blocks to handle the task. I sum up a part of the vector within each block, after which I have two options, one is to use atomicAdd to combine the sum of each block, and the other is to write the result in some global memory and launch another kernel to sum up. Which method do you recommand me to use ?

Comment: @BlameTheBits: If you use an atomic transaction then synchronization isn't necessary. That is the entire point

Comment: @BlameTheBits Hi, when I use atomic method, I only need to sync each block and call atomicAdd, and when I use method of launching another kernel, the SM is synchronized automatically after the first kernel is finished.

Comment: The size of the reduction, the size of the grid, the block size, the kernel design, and the type of GPU you are running on, and probably many other factors are going to influence the final performance outcome for a sum reduction.  My expectation is that in the majority of cases, the atomic finish is going to be faster than launching a second kernel. But you can probably find corner-cases and exceptions.  Couldn't you write your own test in a few minutes that would answer this question for you?  I doubt there is one single answer with no exceptions.

Comment: Oh, right, I'm dumb. Sorry

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for replying !!! Does this mean that calling kernel functions would bring noticable overhead to the program, so it is better for us to carefully design the programs with less kernel functions(which means to squeeze more code in single kernels)?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Also please tell me why atomicAdd is expected to be faster ? What is it that slows down the programs, the kernel launching procedure or the global memory accessing procedure?

Comment: Yes, calling a kernel has some overhead (eg. approximately fixed minimum time cost) regardless of how much work the kernel is doing. Since a classical parallel reduction using a cascaded sequence of kernel calls results in kernels after the first doing less work, the overhead can become significant in a relative way. I believe this also leads towards the answer to "why atomicAdd is expected to be faster?". You can save/eliminate some global read/write activity, and also save the overhead of an additional kernel launch, replacing it with an atomic operation (per threadblock). This can be a win.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for telling me this !! So is it a golden rule that we should try our best to merge kernels together so that we can reduce number of kernel function callings?

Answer (score 1):

> Is cuda atomicAdd operation faster than launch another kernel when we do reduce sum?

For the following test case, using the code lifted from [slides](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/05_Atomics_Reductions_Warp_Shuffle.pdf) 16 and 17 in the training [here](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/calendar/cuda-atomics-reductions-and-warp-shuffle/) ([video](https://vimeo.com/419029739)), it seems to be a bit faster.  The difference is about the cost of kernel launch overhead, which makes sense:

```
$ cat t1834.cu
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>

const int BLOCK_SIZE = 1024;

template <typename T>
__global__ void reduce(const T * __restrict__ gdata, T * __restrict__ out, const int N){
     __shared__ T sdata[BLOCK_SIZE];
     int tid = threadIdx.x;
     sdata[tid] = 0.0;
     size_t idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

     while (idx < N) {  // grid stride loop to load data
        sdata[tid] += gdata[idx];
        idx += gridDim.x*blockDim.x;
        }

     for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>0; s>>=1) {
        __syncthreads();
        if (tid < s)  // parallel sweep reduction
            sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
        }
     if (tid == 0)
#ifndef USE_ATOMIC
         out[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
#else
         atomicAdd(out, sdata[0]);
#endif
}

#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}


typedef float mt;
const int ds = 1048576*8;
int main(){

  mt *h_gdata, *d_gdata, *h_out, *d_out;
  h_gdata = new mt[ds];
  cudaMalloc(&d_gdata, ds*sizeof(mt));
  const int nblocks = 160;
  h_out = new mt[1];
  cudaMalloc(&d_out, nblocks*sizeof(mt));
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) h_gdata[i] = 1;
  cudaMemcpy(d_gdata, h_gdata, ds*sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  reduce<<<nblocks, BLOCK_SIZE>>>(d_gdata, d_out, ds); // warm-up
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaMemset(d_out, 0, sizeof(mt));
  unsigned long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
  reduce<<<nblocks, BLOCK_SIZE>>>(d_gdata, d_out, ds);
#ifndef USE_ATOMIC
  reduce<<<1, BLOCK_SIZE>>>(d_out, d_out, nblocks);
#endif
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(dt);
  cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {std::cout << "CUDA error: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl; return 0;}
  if (h_out[0] != ds) {std::cout << "Reduce Error: " <<  h_out[0] << std::endl;   return 0;}
  std::cout << "Timing: " << dt << "us" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -lineinfo -arch=sm_70 -O3  -o t1834 t1834.cu -std=c++14 -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets
$ ./t1834
Timing: 69us
$ nvcc -lineinfo -arch=sm_70 -O3  -o t1834 t1834.cu -std=c++14 -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -DUSE_ATOMIC
$ ./t1834
Timing: 66us
$
```

(CUDA 11.2, Centos 7, V100 GPU)

Comment: HI, What about the case where ds is extremely large? Whill the overhead of kernel launching becomes constant while the overhead of atomic operation grows linearly ?